# Running Delphi builds under TFS MSBuild

Tags: delphi, msbuild, build-automation

Wanting to build and test a bunch of Borland Delphi 6 projects that are integrated with ASP.NET services.  Had been using WANT and CruiseControl for building Delphi.  With TFS Build agent we can tie all together and do some testing. I am looking for guidance and direction.

One issue I see is that there is no "solution" in a Delphi project to be given to MSBuild as a '<'SolutionToBuild'>'.

```
<SolutionToBuild Include="There is no such thing as a Delphi.sln">
    <Targets></Targets>
    <Properties></Properties>
</SolutionToBuild>
```

Also, I have references to `<UsingTask`> but am a little unsure how to use them. The `<UsingTask`> allows run custom task for Delphi command-line compile.

Your guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: My bad: ...I have references to '<'UsingTask'>' but am a little unsure how to use them.

Comment: Vad 2nd paragraph.  Rewrite:
One issue I see is that there is no "solution" in a Delphi project to be given to MSBuild as a '<'SolutionToBuild'>'. Also, I have references to '<'UsingTask'>' but am a little unsure how to use them. The UsingTask allows run custom task for Delphi command-line compile.

Comment: @Jim Roberts: I included your second comment directly in to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MSBuild to run the Delphi command line compiler. It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure either the IDE supports command line compilation or there is a stand-alone compiler that can be run from the command line. In either case, you would need to create an `<Exec`> task that runs the appropriate command line build tool with the required parameters.

When you say you have "references to `<UsingTask`>" do you mean that you are importing an external MSBuild task? The `<UsingTask`> element is used to pull in a custom MSBuild task that resides in an external assembly (DLL). Once the task is imported, you use it just like you would any other built-in task.

Comment: Yes '<'UsingTask'>' will cause the run my C# DelphiBuild.dll which then will, with parameters from the .proj in a ProcessStartInfo, be given to System.Diagnostics.Process. I've loaded my DelphiBuild.dll on the server.  I think :) my problem is in my XML setup -- but I haven't got to the .dll yet.

Answer (score 1):

Can you upgrade? Delphi 2006+ uses MSBuild by default. There is nothing to configure.

Comment: D2K6+ would be wonderful.  Sigh.  We're headed into the VS world from D6. We're in VS 2008 and D6 on the side.